# sort tuples in lists in python

Tags: python, list, sorting, tuples

i was wondering if there was any simple way around sorting tuples in lists in python, for instance if i have a list:

```
list01 = ([a,b,c],[b,a,d],[d,e,c],[a,f,d])
```

and i sorted it, i would get:

```
([a,b,c],[a,b,d],[c,d,e],[a,d,f])?
```

or even:

```
([a,b,c],[a,b,d],[a,d,f],[c,d,e])
```

if that's easier

Thanx in advance:)

Comment: Btw. it is a tuple of lists, not vice versa.

Comment: Which is to say: you do not have tuples in a list here. You have lists in a tuple. `[]` surround a list. `()` surround a tuple.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> list01 = (['a','b','c'],['b','a','d'],['d','e','c'],['a','f','d'])
>>> map(sorted, list01)
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'd'], ['c', 'd', 'e'], ['a', 'd', 'f']]
>>> sorted(map(sorted, list01))
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'd'], ['a', 'd', 'f'], ['c', 'd', 'e']]
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple as that...

```
list01 = (['a','b','c'],['b','a','d'],['d','e','c'],['a','f','d'])

print(sorted(map(sorted,list01)))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a generator instead:

```
>>> list01 = (['a','b','c'],['b','a','d'],['d','e','c'],['a','f','d'])
>>> tuple((sorted(item) for item in list01))
(['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'd'], ['c', 'd', 'e'], ['a', 'd', 'f'])
```

Map is faster, btw. ;)

```
In [48]: timeit tuple(map(sorted, list01))
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.71 us per loop

In [49]: timeit tuple((sorted(item) for item in list01))
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.26 us per loop
```

Edit: sorting in place is even faster (thanks Karl):

```
In [120]: timeit [item.sort() for item in list01 if False]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 490 ns per loop
```

Comment: Sorting in place doesn't have to create a new tuple. Even faster in my tests (although it does create a new list, it doesn't populate it): `[item.sort() for item in list01 if False]` - for about 0.45 us per loop. ;) On my system, the `map` version is slightly slower and the `sorted` version is significantly faster, so that there's only about a 40% speed difference there instead of the 95% or so you're reporting.

Comment: And, of course, using the ugly `if 0` instead of `if False` shaves off a little bit more, because the name `False` doesn't have to be looked up. So yeah, that's how you micro-optimize in Python (but if it's that important, why aren't you dropping to C?).

Comment: I was just trying to show some examples, it still depends on data. If there are few of them than I'd use the shortest/prettier/most readable one, if there's a lot of them, I'd probably use Cython ;)