# Sorting tuples by element value in Python

Tags: python, list, sorting, tuples

I need to sort a list of tuples in Python by a specific tuple element, let's say it's the second element in this case. I tried

```
sorted(tupList, key = lambda tup: tup[1])
```

I have also tried

```
sorted(tupList, key = itemgetter(1))
'''i imported itemgetter, attrgetter, methodcaller from operator'''
```

but the list was returned the same both times. I checked

[sorting tuples in python with a custom key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4554115/sorting-tuples-in-python-with-a-custom-key)

[sort tuples in lists in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421410/sort-tuples-in-lists-in-python)

https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting

Comment: Reminder: calling `sorted` on a list doesn't modify the original list. If you're doing `sorted(seq); print(seq);`, then you're not going to see any changes. Make sure you're doing `new_thing = sorted(seq); print(new_thing)` or similar.

Comment: o_O Your code seems fine to me. Show input and expected output please?

Comment: Can you provide an example list that causes the problem?

Comment: As is stated by @Kevin, sorted does not mutate a list in place, but returns a new version of it. If you want to mutate in place, you should use `tupList.sort(key=lambda t: t[1])`

Comment: @Kevin you are right. I switched from list.sort() to sorted and forgot I have to save the result somewhere. Please make an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you're calling `sorted` but not assigning the result anywhere.  Something like:

```
tupList = [(2,16), (4, 42), (3, 23)]
sorted(tupList, key = lambda tup: tup[1])
print(tupList)
```

`sorted` creates a new sorted list, rather than modifying the original one. Try:

```
tupList = [(2,16), (4, 42), (3, 23)]
tupList = sorted(tupList, key = lambda tup: tup[1])
print(tupList)
```

Or:

```
tupList = [(2,16), (4, 42), (3, 23)]
tupList.sort(key = lambda tup: tup[1])
print(tupList)
```